# Selecting cities that have 10 or more students and instructors combined in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to show the city, state, number of student residents, number of instructor residents, and total student/instructor residents in that city. The information is contained in 3 tables: ZIPCODE, STUDENT, and INSTRUCTOR.

- The ZIPCODE table has the columns ZIP, CITY, and STATE.
- The STUDENT table has STUDENT_ID and ZIP.
- The INSTRUCTOR table has INSTRUCTOR_ID and ZIP.

I've tried a couple of inner joins, and intersects, but I keep getting a wide variety of errors. I'm still very new with SQL, and am not sure how to actually make this work, any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a mix of union and join for this. I doubt you want intersect. Plenty of ways to do this, here's one

```
SELECT
  Z.city,
  Z.state,
  SUM(case when d.typ = 's' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as count_students,
  SUM(case when d.typ = 'i' then 1 ELSE 0 END) as count_instructors,
  Count(*) as count_all
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT 's' as typ, zip FROM student)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT 'I ' as typ, zip FROM Instructor)
  ) d
  INNER JOIN
  zipcode z
  ON d.zip on z.zip
GROUP BY 
  z.city, z.state
```

I pull all the records out of each student and instructor table and union them to make one big list, make a column to keep track of the type, the sum does the counting, when the type is s, the case when returns a 1. The sum will sum the 1s up as a count. You thus end up with a city/state/typ combination for each row and when grouped on city and state and summed on the typ, it gives a count

Here's another way to do this:

```
SELECT
  Z.city,
  Z.state,
  SUM(s.ct) as count_students,
  SUM(i.ct) as count_instructors,
  SUM(s.ct) + SUM(I.ct) as count_all
FROM
  zipcode z
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT zip, count(*) ct FROM student GROUP BY zip) s
  ON s.zip = z.zip

  LEFT OUTER JOIN  
  (SELECT zip, count(*) as ct FROM Instructor GROUP BY zip) i 
  ON i.zip = z.zip

GROUP BY z.city, z.state
```

We group and count the students and the instructors in their own subqueries producing just a single count per zip and join these (left join) to all the zip codes. We group in a sub query to ensure that there is only ever a 1:1 relationship between zipcode and s/i. If it were 1:many the sums would beome distorted.  Because multiple zips can refer to one city there is another round of grouping and summing to aggregate all the zips from one city